# Can't use onChange with react-bootstrap ToggleButtonGroup

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

So it's been a couple of hours since I spotted this problem and it's getting weirder every minute. The main issue is I can't manage to make the onChange event work on a ToggleButtonGroup.

My code:

```
class ToggleButtonGroupControlled extends React.Component {                                                                                                                                  
    constructor(props, context) {                                                                                                                                     
        super(props, context);                                                                                                                                        

        this.state = {                                                                                                                                                
            value: [1, 3],                                                                                                                                            
        };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);                                                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                                                                 

    onChange(value){                                                                                                                                                  
        alert(value);                                                                                                                                                 
        this.setState({ value });                                                                                                                                     
    };                                                                                                                                                                

    render() {                                                                                                                                                        
        return (                                                                                                                                                      
            <ToggleButtonGroup                                                                                                                                        
              type="checkbox"                                                                                                                                         
              value={this.state.value}                                                                                                                                
              onChange={this.onChange}                                                                                                                                
              >                                                                                                                                                       
              <ToggleButton value={1}>Checkbox 1 (pre-checked)</ToggleButton>                                                                                         
              <ToggleButton value={2}>Checkbox 2</ToggleButton>                                                                                                       
              <ToggleButton value={3}>Checkbox 3 (pre-checked)</ToggleButton>                                                                                         
            </ToggleButtonGroup>                                                                                                                                      
        );                                                                                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

Now, when I select different "checkboxes" the display changes accordingly, but the alert is never fired. Furthermore, inspecting the component through the Chrome React extension shows the state doesn't change, so it's left as an uncontrolled component because the onChange handler is never executed.

The weird part, however, is that this same code is used in the [docs demo](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-groups-checkbox-radio) and it just works. Another strange thing is that in the demo, I can modify the onChange handler via `$r.props.onChange` with React Developer Tools, while in my test I just can't. `ToggleButtonGroup` makes use of `uncontrollable` to return an *uncontrolled* version of the component wrapping the good one. The uncontrolled wrapper has the onChange I pass via props, but the controlled component has a certain `setAndNotify` function from `uncontrollable` attached and it can't be removed.

I really don't know what could be the problem since I think I have discarded all the sensible possibilities, but I might be missing something obvious -- I really hope I am.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You need to bind your `onChange` function.

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc true, I forgot about that, but it doesn't really matter here since the problem is the function is never executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other people encounter this issue as well (Refer to [this](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2734)). Downgrade `react-boostrap` package version should work

Comment: yep, I forgot to check the closed issues (though it doesn't seem solved to me (?)). Anyway, I'm going to try with downgrading.

Comment: As expected it didn't quite work. It looks like they didn't break anything but it's just not working properly / fully yet. In fact, they just modified the export in `index.js` to include this module not even a month ago as per https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/commit/b4e4ffabe9c8b90cfa687769a604a00656311d7e, so it's under active development, much to my regret.
Thank you very much anyway for your time.