# React-Boostrap ToggleButtonGroup onChange not working

Tags: react-bootstrap

It seems the onChange is still broken (refer to similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575135/cant-use-onchange-with-react-bootstrap-togglebuttongroup/49769875#49769875)). 
The onChange will fire however you cannot use event.target.value as the event.target is on a parent of the element with the value attribute. For example, I have something like this:

```
<ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="detect" defaultValue={1} onClick={event => this.onInputMethodChange(event.target)}>
  <ToggleButton value={1}>Translate</ToggleButton>
  <ToggleButton value={2}>Detect</ToggleButton>
</ToggleButtonGroup>
```

when I console.log(event.target) I get a label element but the value is on the input element.

```
<label>
  <input value="2" >
</label>
```

Is there a way to get this input value? It's not ideal but I could at least work with it. Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have typed onClick instead of onChange? You need to either use onChange instead of onClick (if that exists) or have an individual onClick callback for each of the ToggleButtons.

Comment: The documentation says onChange but onChange does not fire. onClick will fire but then I get the issue described above. Maybe using individual onClick is a way to go. I'll try that. Thanks Ricardo. - Just tried this but it's the same issue as described above.

Comment: Here is a snippet: https://codesandbox.io/s/0xm67kpk2l .
If you open the console you'll see that it is logging only the value. Is it not working this way for you?

Comment: I can see this works but it doesn't seem to work for me. Thanks for your help Ricardo, if I could accept your answer I would :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the ID of each button in order for onChange to fire

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).